# Seaborn / Matplotlib: Modify axis limits of bivariate histogram without distorting bin size

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I'm trying to plot two bivariate histogram with the same axis limits. When I just plot both of them without trying to alter either of their axis', I get this (leaving out some boilerplate params data definitions and x/y tick formatting):

```
def create_hist_plot(params, ax, cbar_ax=None, color=GK_GREEN, bins=80):
    result = sns.histplot(
        **params,
        ax=ax,
        kde=True,
        bins=bins,
        color=color,
    )
    return result

ax_2 = create_hist_plot(params_1, ax_2, color=GREEN, bins=40)
ax_3 = create_hist_plot(params_2, ax_3, color=PURPLE, bins=40)
```

[image]

I want to resize the purple histogram so that it has the same axis limits as the green histogram. I've tried manually setting the limits like this (ax_3 is the purple histogram, ax_2 is the green histogram)

```
ax_3.set_ylim(ax_2.get_ylim())
ax_3.set_xlim(ax_2.get_xlim())
```

which gives me

[image]

but notice how the bins in the purple histogram are now distorted. Is there a way to modify the axis limits of the histogram without distorting the bins?

Comment: Could you add the code to create the bivariate histograms? Probably you can add a parameter `bins=` to use the same bins in both histograms.

Comment: I added the relevant code. I am specifying a bin size of 40 for both plots.

Comment: You shouldn't add a simple number for `bins=`, but a pair of vectors, one for `x` and one for `y`. As it is unclear how data and axes are made up, it is hard to show an example. A vector could be something like `np.linspace(min_val, max_val, 40)` using the same min and max for both histograms.

Comment: That is great advice! I messed around with what you said a bit and I got the results I wanted. I'll update my question to include the code I have that worked for me. If you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll mark is as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Ben, please add this as an answer and accept it. Do not include the answer in the question.

Comment: Editing your question to include an answer is deemed somehow inappropriate. If you have time, please ① roll back your question, ② put your answer where it belongs (i.e., in an answer) and ③ possibly accept it, so that future readers know  that it worked for you.

Comment: I added the solution as an answer. I'll mark it as the accepted answer tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [johanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)'s recommendation in the comments, I tried the following and I got the result I wanted.

```
def create_hist_plot(params, ax, cbar_ax=None, color=GK_GREEN, bins=80):
    result = sns.histplot(
        **params,
        ax=ax,
        kde=True,
        bins=bins,
        color=color,
    )
    return result

ax_2 = create_hist_plot(params_1, ax_2, color=GREEN, bins=40)
bins = [
    np.linspace(ax_2.get_xlim()[0], ax_2.get_xlim()[1], 40),
    np.linspace(ax_2.get_ylim()[0], ax_2.get_ylim()[1], 40)
]
ax_3 = create_hist_plot(params_2, ax_3, color=PURPLE, bins=bins)
```

Result
[image]